# How to get a console terminal to show up on a previously headless server

Tags: 14.04, display, hdmi, xserver

I've got a previously headless server that I've plugged a monitor into (via hdmi), a keyboard, and mouse.

I can ssh to the box. If I start X server with `sudo startx` over an SSH prompt I get the X background and I can interact with the keyboard and mouse (e.g. monitor, keyboard, and mouse are connected correctly).

When I stop X server from the ssh session I just get a blank screen. I was expecting a console terminal session from which to start the X server in.

Pressing enter on the keyboard does not wake it up.

> What do I need to do to get a console terminal?

Comment: Connect a monitor, keyboard, and mouse to the server. X is a huge wast of resources on a server. If you need a graphical tool to administrate, use webmin or similar

Comment: Nice, thanks for the tip, I'll look at it. For the moment I just wanted to get in temporarily and use gparted to finish mounting a disk that was started that way. I could do fdisk, but I didn't want to screw something up.

Comment: sudo mount partition mount_point - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display will time out and shut down if a monitor isn't connected to it, and didn't come back online by plugging in a monitor. A reboot brought it up for me.